# Mongoose - Updating a document , adding new keys (having strict:false)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following mongoose model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String, 
    long_name: String,
    address: String,
    telephone: String,
    mobile_phone: String,
    fax: String,
    email: String,
    url: String,
    config:{
        language: String,
        account: String
    },
    items:[{
        name: String,
        internal_id: String,
        reference_code: String,
        description: String
    }]
},{ timestamps: true, strict: false });

var Company = mongoose.model('Company', companySchema);

module.exports = Company;
```

Ok the idea is to let each user insert their own fields in the items array. For example, a user will create a new item with several new key/value pairs. The I will store the new item in the items array:

```
var Company = require('mongoose').model('Company');

exports.createItem = function(req, res, next) {

        var newitem = {
            "name": "Syringe Needels",
            "internal_id": "ID00051",
            "reference_code": "9506",
            "description": "My description",
            "batch": "100",
            "room": "240",
            "barcode": "9201548121136"
        };


      Company.findById(req.company, function(error, company) {
           company.items.push(newitem);
           company.save(function(err, doc){
            return res.status(200).send('The new item has been stored!');
          });

      });
};
```

The keys that are not defined in the schema are not being stores; only name, internal_id, reference_code and description are stored.

How could I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a subdocument with data type as mixed object. This will let you insert / update keys dynamically

```
var companySchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name: String, 
    long_name: String,
    address: String,
    telephone: String,
    mobile_phone: String,
    otherProps : {}
})
```

This (otherProps key) will get the task done